# Scatter subplots in pandas for every column

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn, scatter

I'd like to plot a scatter plot for every pair [df_unempl,df_ipc] columns. The two dataframes go from 2000 to 2020. So, in total 20 scatter plots.

Can this be done with a for loop? In the way that it shows the 20 graphs at a time.

```
unempl=df_unempl
deflac=df_ipc
z=pd.merge_ordered(unempl,deflac,on='Country Code',how='inner')
z=z.fillna(0)


sns.lmplot(x='2000 [YR2000]_x', y='2000 [YR2000]_y', data=z,order=1, 
ci=None, scatter_kws={"s": 10})

sns.lmplot(x='2001 [YR2001]_x', y='2001 [YR2001]_y', data=z,order=1, 
ci=None, scatter_kws={"s": 10})

sns.lmplot(x='2002 [YR2002]_x', y='2002 [YR2002]_y', data=z,order=1, 
ci=None, scatter_kws={"s": 10})

sns.lmplot(x='2003 [YR2003]_x', y='2003 [YR2003]_y', data=z,order=1, 
ci=None, scatter_kws={"s": 10})
.
.
.
sns.lmplot(x='2020 [YR2020]_x', y='2020 [YR2020]_y', data=z,order=1, 
ci=None, scatter_kws={"s": 10})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more precise? I can't really understand your issue. Please explain more...

Comment: Just Edited ;))

Comment: This is still extremely unprecise. Show us an example dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a matplotlib figure with 20 subplots and then redirect the seaborn plot to the matplotlib axes with the keyword argument `ax`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, 4)
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.ravel()):
    year = 2000 + i
    sns.regplot(x=f'{year} [YR{year}]_x', y=f'{year} [YR{year}]_y', data=z,order=1, 
               ci=None, scatter_kws={"s": 10}, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

However from your question it is unclear how the column names are formatted and how the dataframes look like. Therefore I can't tell you how to adjust the arguments of `sns.relplot` so that they fetch the data from the correct columns. I need more info for that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I just edited the question, so it should be more clear now :) My intention is to plot the "Phillips curve" and to show the trade-off between Inflation rate and Unemployment rate. This also would require to have a exponential fitted line in the scatter plot. So far, I got the linear line.

Comment: I edited my answer. You can do it by using format strings. Try it out and let me know if it works. Also by the way you say in your question that the years go from 2000 to 2020 so 20 scatter plots. But that would be 21 scatter plots. My answer therefore will only display the years from 2000 to 2019. You have to use one more subplot by adjusting the numbers in `plt.subplots` if you want 21 plots. You can make a 3 by 7 grid for 21 subplots.

Comment: Thanks that looks pretty good, but what does the parameter 'ax' stands for? I have been looking in the seaborn documentation but I haven't found anything similar. It returns the following error: 'lmplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axs'

Comment: My bad. `lmplot` does not have the `ax` keyword but `regplot` does. Try using `regplot` instead of `lmplot`. `lmplot` is the same as `regplot` only that it is used to plot multiple plots just like you want with rows and columns. But it would require you to have your year in a seperate column, so you would have to reformat you dataframe with a column that has the year and a second column that holds the values corresponding to that year. This would actually be a better organization of your dataframe but in this case the easiest is to just use `regplot` and create the multiple axes yourself.

Comment: KeyError: '{year} [YR{year}]_x'. My apologies but I am not familiar with the syntax.. where the error can be?

Comment: I'm sorry, my answer was a mess. I fixed it, there should have been an `f` before the string in `y=`. So `y=f'{year} [YR{year}]_y'` just like for x. The syntax is the syntax for format strings. You basically take a string with placeholders that are then filled by variables. You make the string a format string by putting an f before it and then specify placeholders with curly brackets, inside of which you put the variables that should be filled in.

Comment: Thanks man for the explanation and for the time you put in it! Works perfectly now. I have now a better understanding of the syntax.. Cheers